# Swagger UI Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swaggerui

I'm using Spring Boot 3.0.2 and wanted to enable Swagger to develop API Documentation. I added dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I'm trying to access http://localhost:5555/swagger-ui/index.html it just shows blank page. It accesses, but doesn't display anything. I only added the dependency and that's all, I didn't make any changes.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1.[как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 2. переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык